# dynamically created radio buttons not displaying

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have an application in which there are several tabs. One of those creates several group boxes and in each of these group boxes I need 10 radio buttons ranging from 1-10. My problem is that I cannot get the radio button to show up and work properly. When I create them if I add them to the current tabs controls all the radio buttons will display but the winform treats them all as one set of radio.

I need the radio buttons in each groupbox to be a set. If I add the buttons to the groupbox the radio buttons will not display. I have played around with the order in which I add the radio button to the groupbox, call the radio buttons `show()` method, add the groupbox to the tabs control, and call the groupbox's `show()` method but no matter what configuration I try these in I can't seem to get the radio buttons to display. I also tried to change the `childIndex` of the radio button but that didn't work either.

Some of you may suggest to just use a drop down or `upDownNumaric` but I actually have the `UpDownNumaric` working but the customer wants it changed to a set of radio buttons. The code I currently have:

```
groupBoxLocation.Y += 45;
GroupBox newGroupBox = new GroupBox();

newGroupBox.Location = groupBoxLocation;
newGroupBox.Text = reader["Description"].ToString().Trim();
newGroupBox.Size = new Size(425, 40);
newGroupBox.Name = ("PS_L_" + newGroupBox.Text).Replace(" ", "").Trim();


RadioButton rateValue;


radioButtonsLocation = new Point(newGroupBox.Location.X - 30, newGroupBox.Location.Y + 15);

tabControl1.TabPages[3].Controls.Add(newGroupBox);

newGroupBox.Show();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    rateValue = new RadioButton();
    radioButtonsLocation = new Point(radioButtonsLocation.X + 41, radioButtonsLocation.Y);

    rateValue.Location = radioButtonsLocation;
    rateValue.Text = (i + 1).ToString().Trim();
    rateValue.Width = 40;
    rateValue.Name = "PI_V_" + newGroupBox.Text.Replace(" ", "") + "_" + i;

    newGroupBox.Controls.Add(rateValue);
    newGroupBox.Controls[rateValue.Name].Show();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your initialization of the radioButtonsLocation. The locations are relative to their parent, not relative to the root container, so try changing

```
radioButtonsLocation = new Point(newGroupBox.Location.X - 30, newGroupBox.Location.Y + 15);
```

to

```
radioButtonsLocation = new Point(0,10);
```

or some similar point based on how you would like your UI to look.

Comment: I cant believe I overlooked that, but thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Happens to us all - I've been programming for 10 years and I had to ask a coworker the difference between `break` and `continue` because I just couldn't remember.